# How can I insert a string to the first iteration of a loop only?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

Okay so I have this array of objects which are dynamic. It can have `100` objects inside or only `one`. I have been rendering html from server side by iterating through the array. That part works fine but what I want to do is I want to insert a piece of `string` to the `first iteration` only. Which means I want the value of power to be in the first iteration, which is `Steve Rogers` and I want the value of power to be in the first `td` just before the anchor tag.

Please note again that `arr` can have any amount of objects.

Here's the code:

```
const arr = [ 
    {
        "name": 'Steve Rogers',
        "age": 90,
        "bio": 'https://www.boomboom.com'
    }, 
    {
        "name": 'Natasha Romanoff',
        "age": 30,
        "bio": 'https://www.bambam.com'
    }
];

const power = 'Super-Strength <br><br>';

const arrMap = arr.map(el => {
    return `
        <td>
            <a href="${el.bio}">Bio</a>
        </td>
        <td>${el.name}</td>
        <td>${el.age}</td>
    `;
});
```

Expected result is an array of two chunk of strings:

```
[
  '<td>
       Power: Super-Strength <br><br>
       <a href="https://www.boomboom.com">Bio</a>
   </td>
   <td>Steve Rogers</td>
   <td>90</td>',

   '<td><a href="https://www.bambam.com">Bio</a></td>
   <td>Natasha Romanoff</td>
   <td>30</td>'
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need pass index parameter to Array.prototype.map as follows:

```js
const arr = [ 
    {
        "name": 'Steve Rogers',
        "age": 90,
        "bio": 'https://www.boomboom.com'
    }, 
    {
        "name": 'Natasha Romanoff',
        "age": 30,
        "bio": 'https://www.bambam.com'
    }
];

const power = 'Super-Strength <br><br>';
const arrMap = arr.map((el, index) => {
    return `
        <td>
            ${index === 0 ? "Power: " + power : ""}<a href="${el.bio}">Bio</a>
        </td>
        <td>${el.name}</td>
        <td>${el.age}</td>
    `;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```js
var arr = [ 
    {
        "name": 'Steve Rogers',
        "age": 90,
        "bio": 'https://www.boomboom.com'
    }, 
    {
        "name": 'Natasha Romanoff',
        "age": 30,
        "bio": 'https://www.bambam.com'
    }
];

var power = 'Super-Strength <br><br>';

var arrMap = arr.map((el,i) => {
    return `<td>${i==0 ? "Power: "+power : ""}<a href="${el.bio}">Bio</a></td><td>${el.name}</td><td>${el.age}</td>`;
});
console.log(arrMap)
```